# Drawing simple lines in OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders on IOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, shader

I am having a hard time trying to draw simple lines through an OpenGL ES 2.0 shader.
I am trying to use `glDrawArrays` with `GL_LINES`, but so far i've been unsuccessful.

My vertex shader is the most basic you can get:

```
attribute vec4 Position; 
attribute vec4 SourceColor; 

uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 ModelView;

varying vec4 DestinationColor; 

void main(void) { 
    DestinationColor = SourceColor; 
    gl_Position = Projection * ModelView * Position;
}
```

And the fragment shader:

```
varying lowp vec4 DestinationColor;

void main(void) {
    gl_FragColor = DestinationColor;
}
```

I have some doubts:

1. How do you setup the Origin and Destination points coordinates?
2. How to setup the Projection and ModelView matrices in this case? With a square, the ModelView matrix will hold the its Center coordinate, but what happens in the case of a Line?

Does anyone have an example?

EDIT:

Ok, i have the following code:

```
    glLineVertices[0].Position[0] = origin.x;
    glLineVertices[0].Position[1] = origin.y;
    glLineVertices[0].Position[2] = 0;
    glLineVertices[0].Color[0] = 1.0f;
    glLineVertices[0].Color[1] = 0.0f;
    glLineVertices[0].Color[2] = 0.0f;
    glLineVertices[0].Color[3] = 0.0f;
    glLineVertices[0].Normal[0] = 0.0f;
    glLineVertices[0].Normal[1] = 0.0f;
    glLineVertices[0].Normal[2] = 1.0f;

    glLineVertices[1].Position[0] = end.x;
    glLineVertices[1].Position[1] = end.y;
    glLineVertices[1].Position[2] = 0;
    glLineVertices[1].Color[0] = 1.0f;
    glLineVertices[1].Color[1] = 0.0f;
    glLineVertices[1].Color[2] = 0.0f;
    glLineVertices[1].Color[3] = 0.0f;
    glLineVertices[1].Normal[0] = 0.0f;
    glLineVertices[1].Normal[1] = 0.0f;
    glLineVertices[1].Normal[2] = 1.0f;

    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(vertexArray);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexStructureSize, glLineVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderManager.currentAttributeVertexPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(shaderManager.currentAttributeVertexPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glLineVertex), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderManager.currentAttributeSourceColor);
    glVertexAttribPointer(shaderManager.currentAttributeSourceColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,  sizeof(glLineVertex), (char *)12);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderManager.currentAttributeVertexNormal);
    glVertexAttribPointer(shaderManager.currentAttributeVertexNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glLineVertex), (char *)28);
```

With a render method:

```
- (void)render
{
    //It might as well be the Identity Matrix, nothing happens either way.
    //modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity;   
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, 0.0f);    
    glUniformMatrix4fv(shaderManager.currentUniformModelViewMatrix, 1, 0, modelViewMatrix.m);

    glBindVertexArrayOES(vertexArray);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, size);  

}
```

And with this projection matrix:

```
_projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 0, self.view.bounds.size.height, -1.0f, 1.0f);

[shaderManager useShaderProgram:@"LineShader"];

glUniformMatrix4fv([shaderManager getUniform:@"Projection" ofShader:@"LineShader"], 1, 0, _projectionMatrix.m);
```

As soon as i use:

```
[lineDraw render];
```

Nothing happens.
Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally figured it out.

These simple lines:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(shaderManager.currentAttributeVertexNormal);
glVertexAttribPointer(shaderManager.currentAttributeVertexNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(glLineVertex), (char *)28);
```

were causing the issue, because i temporarily disabled the use of normals in the shader, commenting out the correspondent attribute. Didn't know that just by doing that, no draw would occur, and neither getError() would throw any error out.

I will consider the above answer as correct, though, because it helped me clarify the coordinates and correspondent matrices calculations. In this example, plain 2D lines, one doesn't need any special modelViewMatrix, it may stay as "GLKMatrix4Identity".

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

1. The "Origin and Destination Points", assuming you mean the two line end points, are just the lines' vertices, in your case the values sent to the `Position` attribute. So when using `glDrawArrays`, the vertex array/VBO bound to the `Position` attribute (using `glVertexAttribPointer` with the appropriate attribute index) contains (or should contain) the start and end points of all the lines stored one after the other. And the array bound to the `SourceColor` attribute of course has to contain those vertices' colors repectively.
2. The `Projection` matrix is setup as always, it contains the projection transformation and is usually either an orthographic projection (e.g. for a parallel 2D view) or a perspective projection (for a "real" view with farther away objects appearing smaller).

   The `ModelView` matrix contains whatever transformation the line set should have and is usually composed of the model transformation, which transforms the vertices of the line set from its local coordinate system into the world coordinate system, and the view transformation, which transforms the vertices from world space into camera space (from which they then get transformed by the projection transformation).

   So for a square it doesn't just need to contain the sqaure's center, it just depends how you want to transform it and what values its untransformed vertices have (the ones you send to OpenGL through the `Position` attribute). Just keep in mind, that the raw vertices you send to the `Position` attribute are in local space of the line set and are then transformed into world space (and further into view space) by the `ModelView` matrix.

   So if your line has the vertices (0,0) and (1,1), the line's pivot point (the origin of its local coordinate system) is at the start point, whereas a line from (-1,0) to (1,0) has its local origin at its center point. It just depends on the actual vertices of your lines.

But of course, if all this sound very alien to you, you should delve a little deeper into the basics of OpenGL and computer graphics in general.

Comment: In this case i'm using, for a projection matrix: `GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 0, self.view.bounds.size.height, -1.0f, 1.0f);`, and, for a ModelView matrix: `GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, 0.0f);`, i.e. a translation of any kind. Given these matrices, i assume the vertices should be in screen coordinates, like, for instance, Origin(100, 100), End(200, 200) ?

Comment: I setup all of the steps you recommended (i adapted some functions that i already setup with textured squares with success), and when i call glDrawArrays(GL_LINES,etc); nothing happens...

Comment: @NunoMiguelFonseca Correct, indeed.

Comment: @NunoMiguelFonseca Then you should show your code, otherwise it's hard to tell any errors.